# MVC 4 - Bootstrap Typeahead source with an ActionResult

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead.js

I'm using MVC 4 and Entity Framework to develop an intranet web app. On one of my views, I have to implement the autocomplete feature. To do that, I'm using Bootstrap Typeahead. I tried to pass my action (so my function) to feed the input element but it seems that it doesn't work.

Here is my action result which returns an Json :

```
public ActionResult AutoComplete(string term)
{
    var result = db.Persons.Where(p => p.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(term.ToLower()) || p.LastName.ToLower().Contains(term.ToLower())).ToList().Select(p => p.FullName).ToList();

    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

}
```

My View and my script :

```
@model IEnumerable<BuSIMaterial.Models.Person>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";

}


<link href="/Content/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


<h2>Index</h2>


<input type="text" class="typeahead" data-provide="typeahead">



@section Scripts
{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")

        $(".typeahead").typeahead({
            source: function (query, process) {
                var persons = [];
                map = {};

                // This is going to make an HTTP post request to the controller
                return $.post('/Person/AutoComplete', { query: query }, function (data) {

                    // Loop through and push to the array
                    $.each(data, function (i, person) {
                        map[person.Name] = person;
                        map[person.F]
                        persons.push(country.Name);
                    });

                    // Process the details
                    process(countries);
                });
            },
            updater: function (item) {
                var selectedShortCode = map[item].ShortCode;

                // Set the text to our selected id
                $("#details").text("Selected : " + selectedShortCode);
                return item;
            }
        });


    </script>
}
```

In my master page, I call the Bootstrap jquery file(s). Any idea about what's going on?

Comment: Can you tell us what is not working? Are you getting a 500 error, or 404 error on the AJAX request? Javascript errors?? Also you might want to decorate your controller action with `[HttpPost]` attribute as you are doing a post request via AJAX.

Comment: Also, there is no start tag to your `</script>`. You need to have your typeahead code wrapped in `$(document).ready(function() { })`

Comment: ALSO in your post request you are sending `/Person/AutoComplete` a parameter named `query`. Your controller action is looking for a parameter named `term`. There are MANY errors with this code.